# pandas groupby and adding new column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a dataframe which has 3 columns and what I'm trying to do is: group by col1 and col2 and get the max value of col3 and also get second max value of col3 but insert it as a new column: col 4

I was able to group it using the below but don't know how to get the second max and insert it as another column:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['COL1', 'COL2']).agg({'COL3': 'max'})

   COL1  COL2  COL3
0   A    1      0.2 
1   A    1      0.4
3   B    4      0.7
```

Wanted output:

```
   COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
0   A    1      0.4  0.2
3   B    4      0.7  0.7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html). The following solution takes advantage of the fact that the `Series` constructor will broadcast values to match the shape of the index.

```
df.groupby(['COL1', 'COL2'])['COL3'].apply(
    lambda s: pd.Series(s.nlargest(2).values, index=['COL3', 'COL4'])
).unstack()
```

returns

```
           COL3  COL4
COL1 COL2            
A    1      0.4   0.2
B    4      0.7   0.7
```

Answer (score 1):

First [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for aggregate `head` for first and second max value and then select by `iat` for avoid error if only group with one value:

```
grouped = (df.sort_values(['COL1','COL2','COL3'], ascending=[True, True, False])
             .groupby(['COL1', 'COL2'])['COL3']
             .agg(['max', lambda x: x.head(2).iat[-1]])
          )
grouped.columns = ['COL3','COL4']
grouped = grouped.reset_index()
print (grouped)
  COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
0    A     1   0.4   0.2
1    B     4   0.7   0.7
```

Answer (score 1):

use the nlargest function with group by and then reset index:

```
df2 = df.groupby(
          ['COL1', 'COL2']
      ).apply(
          lambda x: pd.Series(x.COL3.nlargest(2).values, index=['COL3', 'COL4'])
      ).reset_index()
```

outputs:

```
   COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
0   A    1      0.4  0.2
1   B    4      0.7  0.7
```

Comment: This is the same as my answer :)

Comment: yup, you're right. I hadn't noticed yours when I posted.